# Can there particles which do not interact with matter at all?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, dark-matter

Weakly interacting massive particles (WIMPs) are hypothetical particles that are one of the proposed candidates for dark matter. They are proposed to have very weak interaction with ordinary matter particles, which got me thinking that can there be other particles that have no interaction with matter at all (not even gravitational). Also is it possible that these particles have their own set of interactions, completely different from known four kinds of interactions between ordinary matter particles?

Comment: It is important to note, that "weakly" means that it doesn't participate in Electromagnetic nor Strong interactions only interacts via the weak interaction. For more details check out  the standard model. Wimps are hypothetical, and most of the wimps are already ruled out by many calculations and measurements.

Comment: Gravity might be the weakest of the forces but it's present for every particle in the universe because it couples to both mass and energy (photons experience gravitational forces).

Answer (score 1):

The question whether or not non-interacting particles exists is not part of physics. As long as these particles have no interaction what-so-ever we have no way to measure them. Hence, there is no consequence of their existence. Personally it follows that this is therefore a **non fruitful question**.

I know that the Pauli exclusion principle is not based on an interaction, but a principle about symmetries. Hence, the above is only true if we assume that there are no symmetry principles involved with the non-interacting particles as well.